# How to add a Maven dependency from a remote repository to my Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Seriously guys? I cannot see why it should be that difficult!!!

I am coming from a C# background, so I am a newbie here.

My needs are simple, I am creating a new Java console application in Eclipse, I want to be able to use a library (in my case JSch) and I decided to use Maven.

After creating the project as a Java project, I right-clicked the project, and chose to convert it to Maven project and chose 'POM' rather than 'JAR' (was recommended in one of the stackoverflow answers).

Then I right-clicked the project again, chose Maven > Add dependency, found 'JSch' and added it.

Now what, I still cannot see any change in the project tree, no package is added and I cannot start using the added dependency in code.

All answers and forums are talking about something else, some are talking about using the command line or talking about creating Maven module projects which is not my interest.

Any help? What should I do next? where did the added dependent package go?

Comment: Have you taken a look into the pom.xml file? Does the JSch dependencies appear their ?

Comment: Yes, and I found two panels: dependencies and dependency management, so I added it to the management list as well although I don't know what does it do.

Comment: so normally what happens next? should I expect seeing it in the project tree?

Comment: Have you tried: Right Click ->Maven -> Update Project ?

Comment: yes, nothing happens.
I also tried both while 'workspace resolution' is enabled and disabled. Nothing is happening in both cases. Although I still don't know what does it mean in any of the cases.

Comment: Please guys describe to me what should I expect to start with. Do I see the project tree changed to show the dependency? Is there any tutorial to say these exact steps?

Comment: Can you post pom.xml?

Comment: What happens when you try to run your code ?

Comment: as @Desaretius mentioned update project and if auto build is not activate build project manually

Comment: And the package should be under Maven Dependencies, make sure you see a logo with the 'M' letter next to your project so you know eclipse recognize your project as maven project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to start with a new project and instead of creating Java project, create Maven project and move your sources to `src/main/java`, that would be a lot simpler than conversions, which are not working as one would expect...

Most important (and not intuitive) thing is to select "Create simple project" option.

[image: New Maven Project > Create a simple project (Eclipse)]

---

You can specify, how to name the project in Eclipse in Advanced option, I'm using `[name]` (logically, you have to specify it)

[image: Specifying name for Maven project in Eclipse]

Comment: When I do so, I cannot see the project name, instead there is a group ID and artifact ID. Sorry if I ask about obvious stuff, but I couldn't find a tutorial for beginners to describe these stuff. Also remember my project is not a Maven module, it just consume Maven libraries.

Comment: I've tried creating the project as Maven instead of conversion and also followed the tutorial at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

It is all working now, thanks

Comment: @Bishoy I agree, that default (group ID) is strange, I added info about `Name template` option from `Advanced` section of the wizard...